# ASP.NET Core 7: using OpenTelemetry to send traces/metrics to Grafana

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, grafana, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I'm trying to send metrics/traces from my ASP.NET Core 7 application to Grafana.

Here's my Docker Compose file.

```yaml
version: '3.4'

networks:
  my-network:
    name: my_network

services:
  sample.restaurant.server:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}samplerestaurantserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: sample/Sample.Restaurant.Server/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=grpc://otel-collector:4317
      - OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=otlp
      - OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=Sample.Restaurant.Server
    ports:
      - 54576:80
      - 54577:443
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    depends_on:
      - database
      - otel-collector
    networks:
      - my-network
  otel-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector
    ports:
      - 4317:4317
    volumes:
      - ./collector-config.yml:/etc/otel-collector/collector-config.yml
    networks:
      - my-network
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafanaa
    depends_on:
      - otel-collector
    networks:
      - my-network

volumes:
  grafana_data: {}
```

And here's my collector config:

```yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:

exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: otel-collector:4317

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [otlp]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [otlp]
```

And here's my service collection extension method that configures `OpenTelemetry`.

```cs
public static class TelemetryConfiguration
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddTelemetry(this IServiceCollection services,
        IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment,
        string telemetryNamespace)
    {
        services.AddOpenTelemetry()
            .ConfigureResource(resource =>
            {
                resource
                    .AddService(
                        serviceName: webHostEnvironment.ApplicationName,
                        serviceNamespace: telemetryNamespace,
                        serviceVersion: Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().Version?.ToString() ?? "1.0.0",
                        serviceInstanceId: Environment.MachineName)
                    .AddAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "deployment.environment", webHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName }
                    });
            })
            .WithMetrics(metrics =>
            {
                metrics
                    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                    .AddConsoleExporter((exporterOptions, metricReaderOptions) =>
                    {
                        metricReaderOptions.PeriodicExportingMetricReaderOptions.ExportIntervalMilliseconds = 1000;
                    })
                    .AddOtlpExporter(builder => builder.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:4317"));
            })
            .WithTracing(tracing =>
            {
                tracing
                    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                    .AddConsoleExporter()
                    .AddOtlpExporter(builder => builder.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:4317"));
            });

        return services;
    }
}
```

Firstly, is this correctly configured?

Secondly, how do I setup the data source in Grafana to receive the data from my collector?

Comment: I think your config will not work: you are trying to use `localhost`, while connecting between different containers, this is incorrect. If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you should use `new Uri("http://otel-collector:4317")` instead.

Comment: And regarding Grafana, AFAIK, otel is not a proper data source - it is mere universal processor of metrics, logs and such, but it doesn't store those. You need something to store data, that will be used by Grafana for visualization. This might be Prometheus, for example. Please look at this [demo architecture](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/demo/architecture/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're attempting to use the OpenTelemetry collector as a Datastore. It collects, processes and forwards data to datastores, so in your example, you'll need to add a series of datastores for the various signals.

My recommendation would be:

- Traces - Jaeger
- Metrics - Prometheus
- Logs - OpenSearch

If you want to, you can then use the free local version of Grafana to visualise things like Metrics.

For production, I'd highly recommend thinking about a SaaS solution as scaling of those can be hard if you're not used to running lots of containers and datastores. That said, all of those OSS/Free solutions can be hosted and scaled if you choose to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using Grafana Cloud for storing your data, it's quite simple to ingest OTLP. Here's [the related documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/monitor-infrastructure/otlp/send-data-otlp/).

You would need to [sign up for Grafana Cloud](https://grafana.com/products/cloud/) (there's a free tier) and change your collector config according to the template below:

```
extensions:
  basicauth/otlp:
    client_auth:
      username: <instanceID>
      password: <Cloud Access Policy token>

exporters:
  otlphttp:
    auth:
      authenticator: basicauth/otlp
    endpoint: https://otlp-gateway-<zone>.grafana.net/otlp

service:
  extensions: [basicauth/otlp]
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [...]
      processors: [...]
      exporters: [..., otlphttp]
    traces:
      receivers: [...]
      processors: [...]
      exporters: [..., otlphttp]
    logs:
      receivers: [...]
      processors: [...]
      exporters: [..., otlphttp]
```

Comment: No, trying to use the Grafana container within Docker Compose run locally on my laptop